# scrapy elasticsearch integration not working

Tags: python, scrapy, elasticsearch-plugin

Need help to figure out why the integration between scrapy and elasticsearch wont work on my local box.

The only difference between the documentation and my settings is that ITEM_PIPELINES is shown as a list in the doc for the scrapyelasticsearch - [https://github.com/knockrentals/scrapy-elasticsearch] vs. a dict.

When I tried the list setting, and ran scrapy i got an error.

Here's what the log says:

> 2016-06-14 23:43:25 [root] DEBUG: Generated unique key >6a67a8c26bfa28a0567906de
>   bc45695193d237e
>   2016-06-14 23:43:25 [root] DEBUG: Item sent to Elastic Search >individualcontent

But, when I query ES, i dont get anything back.

> http://localhost:9200/individualcontent/_search?q=* returns empty

Settings.py:

```
# Configure item pipelines
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'scrapyelasticsearch.scrapyelasticsearch.ElasticSearchPipeline' : 100,
  }


ELASTICSEARCH_SERVERS = ['http://127.0.0.1:9200'] - I tried localhost:9200 as well
ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX = 'individualcontent' 
ELASTICSEARCH_TYPE = 'items' 
ELASTICSEARCH_UNIQ_KEY = 'url'
```

Items Def:

```
title=scrapy.Field()
url=scrapy.Field()
desc=scrapy.Field()
img_links=scrapy.Field()
pdf_links=scrapy.Field()
```

Parse_Content Code:

```
def parse_contents(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//body'):
        item = DmozItem()
        item['title'] = sel.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
        item['url'] = response.url #self.xpath('/a@href').extract()
        item['desc'] = sel.xpath('//meta').extract()
        item['img_links'] = sel.xpath("//img[contains (@src, '.png')]").extract()
        item['pdf_links'] = sel.xpath("//a[contains (@href, '.pdf')]").extract()
        yield item
```

**EDIT**

Error when setting a list for ITEM_PIPELINES as in docs

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = [
'scrapyelasticsearch.scrapyelasticsearch.ElasticSearchPipeline',
]
```

> [Anaconda2] C:\Users\TMB\Python\tutorial>scrapy crawl individualcontent
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "c:\anaconda2\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
>      "**main**", fname, loader, pkg_name)
>    File "c:\anaconda2\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
>      exec code in run_globals
>    File "C:\Anaconda2\Scripts\scrapy.exe__main__.py", line 9, in 
>    File "c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 108, in >execute
>      settings = get_project_settings()
>    File "c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\project.py", line 60, in >get
>   _project_settings
>      settings.setmodule(settings_module_path, priority='project')
>    File "c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\settings__init__.py", line >285, i
>   n setmodule
>      self.set(key, getattr(module, key), priority)
>    File "c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\settings__init__.py", line >260, i
>   n set
>      self.attributes[name].set(value, priority)
>    File "c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\settings__init__.py", line 55, in
>   set
>      value = BaseSettings(value, priority=>priority)
>    File "c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\settings__init__.py", line >91, in
>   **init**
>      self.update(values, priority)
>    File "c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\settings__init__.py", line >>317, i
>   n update
>      for name, value in six.iteritems(values):
>    File "c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 599, in iteritems
>      return d.iteritems(**kw)
>   AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: what was the error that you got?

Comment: I maintain this library, please try the latest version of the library as I made a lot of changes and addressed the bug you experienced.